# unable to install firebase tools cli using windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, firebase, npm, firebase-tools

Hi i unable to install the firebase tools via commandline in the windows

im using this below command

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

after entering this command i m getting this below error

> npm ERR! path C:\Users\data\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules
>
> npm ERR! code ELOOP
>
> npm ERR! errno -4067
>
> npm ERR! syscall mkdir
>
> npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, mkdir 'C:\Users\data\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\data\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-01-20T13_22_41_404Z-debug.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can try installing the 
**`npm i -g firebase-tools@v3.16.0`** version and try to install the 
 **`npm install windows-build-tools`**in your local folder and after that install
**`npm install node-gyp`** in your local folder  and before doing all these try to disable your antivirus

Comment: Yup, windows build tools did it for me. +1

Answer (score 5):

Latest version seems to have a problem.

Try installing one previous version:

`npm i -g firebase-tools@v3.17.2`

**UPDATE:**

Before doing so, it might be better to uninstall faulty one:

`npm uninstall -g firebase-tools`

also make sure you have `windows-build-tools` installed (though I have it on my machines, error you share doesn't really seem to be related to this)

`npm --add-python-to-path='true' --debug install --global windows-build-tools`

**UPDATE 2**

I've updated my Node & NPM versions and then to latest Firebase Tools.

Still getting `WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1` error, but since it's a warning, I've decided to give it a try. So far no problems.

**UPDATE 3**

`windows-build-tools` package got an update yesterday so I installed it with hope it solves problems installing latest version of `firebase-tools`. It did not, same errors occur.

Comment: after executing the windows build tools command im getting the below error npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: windows-build-tool@latest

Comment: tool**s** with an "s"

Comment: Try temporarily removing `%USERPROFILE%\.node-gyp\<version>\include\node\openssl` and the build of gRPC should go through.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -sL firebase.tools | bash
```

This worked for me, don't know if it's really relevant, got if from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools)

Answer (score -2):

npm ERR! code E404 npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@google-cloud%2fpubsub/firebase-tools/firebase-tools npm ERR! 404 npm ERR! 404 'firebase-tools@latest' is not in the npm registry. npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!) npm ERR! 404 npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url. npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! C:\Users\jsmma\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-05-02T14_58_23_615Z-debug.log

Comment: Please edit and use proper [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for your answer,