# Grpc error while installing Firebase for React

Tags: reactjs, firebase

*I've been trying to fix this error for 2 days now. All I did to get the error was:*

1. create-react-app appname
2. cd appname
3. npm install firebase --save (and that's the part that failed to install correctly)

*These are the major fixes I've tried:*

- Installed latest version of Python 3 and added it to the windows path variable.
- Manually downloaded grpc and added it to the project.
- Updated Node to v10+.

I also tried other minor things not worth mentioning, but it didn't make a difference. None of them worked. I tried with multiple clean react apps so react wasn't the issue either.

```
C:\Users\Future\Desktop\react-turbo>npm i firebase --save

> grpc@1.10.1 install C:\Users\Future\Desktop\react-turbo\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.10.1/node-v64-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.0.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.EXE", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:149:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\\Users\\Future\\Desktop\\react-turbo\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\Future\\Desktop\\react-turbo\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Future\Desktop\react-turbo\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v10.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\Future\Desktop\react-turbo\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\Future\Desktop\react-turbo\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Future\Desktop\react-turbo\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:947:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:236:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Future\\Desktop\\react-turbo\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Future\Desktop\react-turbo\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.0.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\Future\Desktop\react-turbo\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\Future\Desktop\react-turbo\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown' (1)
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.10.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Future\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-07T15_01_00_277Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will recommend that instead of installing `node` latest version (which might not be well supported by all libraries) try to use the `v8.11` stable version.

Then there are couple of actions/trick to handle this thing:

1. You might be using `Windows 10`, so try to disable your antivirus and then try again. If on `Linux` try to use command `sudo` in start.
2. Check this as well: [unable to install firebase tools cli using windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48356718/unable-to-install-firebase-tools-cli-using-windows-10/48357822#48357822)
3. And this: [Error with npm install - a pre-gyp error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674390/error-with-npm-install-a-pre-gyp-error?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

**Additional Information**
In reference to learning `Firebase` these might help you as well:

https://medium.com/quick-code/how-to-integrate-react-redux-and-firebase-in-3-simple-steps-c44804a6af38

https://www.codementor.io/yurio/all-you-need-is-react-firebase-4v7g9p4kf

Comment: The problem was either Node since I had only v10+ versions or the standard Windows Antivirus, maybe even both :-) Disabled the Antivirus and installed Node LTS v8.11 and now it works. You're a life saver, thank you again Muhammad =] I'll never forget this. Now I can continue working on my web app, it's a long way to go from this point.

Comment: Just to update node `v.10` works fine for me now, it seems to be a problem with `v.11+`

Answer (score 2):

I needed to downgrade node from 10.12 to 8.11

```
node -v
```

v10.12.0

```
npm install -g n
n 8.11.1
mode -v
```

v8.11.1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is relevant, but I was also getting similar errors.
I was trying to do install the firebase using expo (as recommended in the docs)

`expo install firebase`

and this was failing for me. I noticed that the issue was related to my package-lock.json where `node-pre-gyp` was getting added. Wasted some time, but finally the issue was resolved when I did a npm install (and not expo install)
Hope this helps people in the future.

`npm install firebase --save`